# Cannot post code due to post size

Tags: support, code

I was trying to ask a question and include a code source.

The problem I faced was running into the maximum size of a post.  Even when using the stack snippet, I could not post my code. So I tried to instead use a jsfiddle link, but that was not allowed also.

How do I post my code?

Answer (score 17):

It sounds like you are trying to get help debugging some code (that is, you don't know where the problem is). If that's the case, then your question is actually off-topic on SO.
See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), specifically:

> *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.*

If you actually do know where the problem is and you have a specific question, then please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Huge walls of code are very difficult to understand and respond to and generally won't help other visitors to the site.

Comment: **Minimal** being the operative word in that sentence.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the code you are posting and see what you can cut out that is not needed to answer the question, the post limit is pretty large and if you are posting that much code it is likely that there is more code than needed in order to see the problem and help solve it.

Comment: just I want to include the htmlview when runnig the code, in order to explain the issue i am facing

Comment: @Khouloud The more code you provide the longer it will take someone to read through the code and figure out the problem which will stop some people from attempting to help.

Comment: Yup 'huge pile of JS - next...'

Answer (score 0):

- If there is that much code, then you haven't done enough work to isolate the problem.
- If you found a way to post all the code, no-one would bother to answer the question anyway.

Comment: I post it just to make it possible to be runned, but the code does not contain any problem